# Crawl multiple pages at once

Tags: python, optimization, multithreading, web-scraping, breadth-first-search

This an update to [my last question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64506/basic-search-engine).

I want to process multiple pages at once pulling URLs from `tier_list` in the `crawl_web` method. The problem I am having is `crawl_web` already has two threads to crawl and index simultaneously, and the `.join()` seems to prevent opening more than one page.

```
import urllib2, collections, threading, robotparser, urlparse, Queue
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
q = Queue.Queue()

def get_page_links(page, crawled, to_crawl, next_tier, robot_set):
    #respect the robots.txt and returns all urls from page
    rp = robotparser.RobotFileParser()
    links = []    
    uparse = urlparse.urlparse
    for link in page[1].find_all('a'):
        url = link.get('href')
        base_url = (uparse(page[0]).scheme + '://' + uparse(page[0]).netloc)
        if base_url not in robot_set:
            robot_set.add(base_url)
            rp.set_url(urlparse.urljoin(base_url,'robots.txt'))
            rp.read()
        abs_url = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, url)
        if rp.can_fetch('*', abs_url): 
            links.append(abs_url)
    links = set(links)
    next_tier.extend(links)
    to_crawl.update(links)
    to_crawl.remove(page[0])
    crawled.add(page[0])

def get_page(url):
    #return page html from url
    try:
        return [url,BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())]
    except:
        return [url,BeautifulSoup("")] 

def get_page_words(page, word_index):
    #pulls words off page to be indexed
    url = page[0]
    words = page[1].get_text()    
    to_remove = '{}[]«#$%^&*._,1234567890+=<>/\()":;!?'
    bad_words = set(['http','www','com','https','gov','org','edu','imgs'])
    for i in to_remove:
        words = words.replace(i, ' ').lower()       
    words = words.split()
    for word in words:
        if word in word_index:
            word_index[word].add(url)
        elif len(word) < 15 and word not in bad_words:
            word_index[word] = set([url])

def crawl_web(url, maxdepth):
    #controls crawl depth, updates url lists and word_index 
    depth = 0
    robot_set = set()
    crawled = set()
    to_crawl = set([url])
    word_index = {}
    tier_list = [[url]]
    while depth < maxdepth:
        next_tier = []
        for url in tier_list[depth]:
            page = get_page(url)
            t1 = threading.Thread(target = get_page_links, args = (page, 
                                      crawled, to_crawl, next_tier, robot_set))
            t2 = threading.Thread(target = get_page_words, args = (page,
                                                                   word_index))
            t1.start()
            t2.start()
            t1.join()
            t2.join()
        tier_list.append(next_tier)
        depth += 1
    return crawled, to_crawl, word_index, tier_list

def search_engine(target_string, word_index):
    #searches word_bank for words in string, returns urls words are found at
    targets = list(set(target_string.split()))
    result =[]
    for word in targets:
        if word in word_index:
            result += word_index[word]
    ans = collections.Counter(result).most_common(3)
    return ans

result = crawl_web('http://xkcd.com',2)
word_index = result[2]
print result[0]
print search_engine('starting blogs about', word_index)
```

Answer (score 1):

While I can't answer to your main question about crawling multiple pages at once,
I have a couple of comments about this code.

#### `get_page_links`

In this code, it seems that `base_url` and the `if` that follows should be outside of the `for` loop:

> ```
> links = []
> for link in page[1].find_all('a'):
>     url = link.get('href')
>     base_url = (uparse(page[0]).scheme + '://' + uparse(page[0]).netloc)
>     if base_url not in robot_set:
>         robot_set.add(base_url)
>         rp.set_url(urlparse.urljoin(base_url,'robots.txt'))
>         rp.read()
>     abs_url = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, url)
>     if rp.can_fetch('*', abs_url): 
>         links.append(abs_url)
> links = set(links)
> ```

Also, instead of `links = set(links)`,
it would be better to make `links` a `set` in the first place.

Rewriting the above code like this would be more efficient:

```
links = set()
base_url = uparse(page[0]).scheme + '://' + uparse(page[0]).netloc
if base_url not in robot_set:
    robot_set.add(base_url)
    rp.set_url(urlparse.urljoin(base_url, 'robots.txt'))
    rp.read()
for link in page[1].find_all('a'):
    url = link.get('href')
    abs_url = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, url)
    if rp.can_fetch('*', abs_url):
        links.add(abs_url)
```

#### `get_page`

It would be better to specify in the `except` clause the type of error that can be raised.

#### `get_page_words`

This expression contains the non-ascii character `«`,
and the posted code doesn't contain an encoding declaration:

> ```
> to_remove = '{}[]«#$%^&*._,1234567890+=<>/\()":;!?'
> ```

You can declare `utf-8` encoding by adding this line at the top of the file:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

---

> ```
> to_remove = '{}[]«#$%^&*._,1234567890+=<>/\()":;!?'
> for i in to_remove:
>     words = words.replace(i, ' ').lower()
> ```

One problem here is that `words` is lowercased in every iteration,
when it would be enough to lowercase just once, before starting the loop.

But the bigger problem is the loop itself:
it would be much more efficient to use a regular expression to get rid of all the unwanted characters, for example like this:

```
import re
re_nonword = re.compile(r'[{}[\]«#$%^&*._,1234567890+=<>/\()":;!?]')
words = re_nonword.sub(' ', words)
```

#### set literals

Instead of this:

> ```
> bad_words = set(['http','www','com','https','gov','org','edu','imgs'])
> ```

As of Python 2.7, you can write using *set literals*, like this:

```
bad_words = {'http', 'www', 'com', 'https', 'gov', 'org', 'edu', 'imgs'}
```

I also put spaces after the commas, to follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).